# Laravel 7 Mail attachment with excel file using Maatwebsite\Excel 3.1

Tags: laravel

I want to attached excel file (xlsx format) in my email without saving file on the server.
I already have a working code for download.
Following is what i am trying to do and getting error.

---

### Code

### $excelFile = Excel::download(new OrderExport($this->order), 'Order-'. $this->order->id . '.xlsx');
$mail->attach($excelFile, ['as' => 'Order-'. $this->order->id . '.xlsx']);

---

### Error

### Unable to open file for reading [HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: public
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Order-4.xlsx
Date: Wed, 05 Aug 2020 13:55:24 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 05 Aug 2020 13:55:24 GMT]

I am using Laravel 7.x and Maatwebsite\Excel 3.1

Answer (score 3):

I got it fixed with the following code

```
$excelFile = Excel::raw(new OrderExport($this->order), \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::XLSX);
$mail->attachData($excelFile, 'Order-'. $this->order->id . '.xlsx');
```